# Cannot order IBM Cloud virtual servers with suspended billing using a Softlayer image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, suspend

I'm an active user of Softlayer suspend billing, but I have to restore some VSIs in SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER to use the suspend profile. I can't find the parameter for image restore in the slcli. Does anyone have a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slcli order place` builds a [orderData](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order/) and this is send in the request through the [placeOrder](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method so I recommend to remove the OS price and add **imageTemplateId** in the **--extras** parameter as following:

```
 --extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "suspendable", "domain": "ibmcloud.com"}], "imageTemplateId": 1332123}'
```

Replace the value 1332123 with your image id.